# Can i watch clicks in angular js? I need to close a pop up dispatched from an external event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, event-handling, watch

I have a huge application with a lot of information and different functionalities. There is an external d3 directive (the d3 graphic is embebed on the view that im working on) and i have another popup that show up when i click in some points on the graphic.

Some event is fired in that directive (is external and i dont have to do anything there) with a `$scope.$emit("someEvent")`, I received it in my controller with `$scope.$on("someEvent", function(event){//here a pop up with information is opened})`

My functionality needs that a few clicks still firing news pop ups (always the last one will be shown and that is already solved with the emit of someEvent) the problem is with the rest of the clicks outside the pop up, how can I get them for closing it?.

Right now i have this structure in my controller

```
$scope.closePopup = function () {
  $scope.showPopup = false;
}

$scope.$on("someEvent", function(event){
  //here a pop up with information is opened not always is true
  //if a dont have information is false, this is just representative
  $scope.showPopup = true;
  if ($scope.showPopup) {
    $scope.$emit("popupOpened");
  }
}) 

$scope.$on("popupOpened",function (event) {
  //and here i need to add a listener o something for catching clicks 
  //and asociate them to the $scope.closePopup () function.
  //also, i need to know if thoose clicks are firing someEvent to...
})
```

I have to catch clicks from all the view, any click should be catched. I have tried with `document.getElementById("idview").onclick = function () { $scope.closePopup() };` in `$scope.$on("someEvent")` but this is fired the first time and never show up because is opened and closed in the same click. Thats the reason why I have refactor it with a new $emit

I appreciate some approach or clue for doing this!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what your desired end result is? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: yes, off course. i want to open a pop up when i click in some points of the screen. After that, once it is opened, i need to close it when i click outside the pop up and im not clicking on that points that open new pop ups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open / close a popup, **you can simply add/remove a class** on the popup container, or on the `body` tag of your document app.

Example using `$scope.showPopin` that you've mentionned :

```
<button ng-click="showPopup = !showPopup">Toggle the popup !</button>

...

<div class="popin-container" ng-class="showPopup ? 'visible' : ''">
  <div class="popin-background" ng-click="showPopup = false"></div>
  <div class="popin"></div>
</div>
```

Assuming `.popin-background` is an element (transparent or not) behind your popin, then if you click wherever out of the popin (so : in `.popin-background` element) you will close the popin (= remove the `.visible` class).

Then **you can handle its display / animation with CSS**.

*I did not use your approach (event emitters / listeners) as it doesn't seems necessary here, **Angular already listens to its scopes variables for change**, so you can play with in your view.*

Comment: This is better than my answer. Heads up, though, the asker was asking about how the popup can be closed if the user clicks anywhere but the popup.

Comment: This should do the job now.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! the view is huge and there's a lot of events doing different stuffs, i have lists, filters, graphics, etc. In this case the event dispatcher of pop up comes from a d3 directive. That's why im not keeping simple like you do in the example. I need something after received the event in the $on that listen for new clicks and if they are outside the pop up calls closePopup.

Comment: You should have mentionned that in your question. How does the popin directive you use look ? You need to catch clicks on which element ?

Comment: You are right, its more descriptive now! i have yo catch from all the view, any click should be catched. i have tried with               document.getElementById("idview").onclick = function () { $scope.closePopup() }; but this is fired the first time and never show up because is opened and closed in the same click.

Comment: Just use ng-click="closePopup()" on idView element ?